# DataTable setting td overflow after fnDrawCallback

Tags: html, css, html-table, datatable

i'm trying to give a td an overflow class if its width exceeds normal width.

```
fnDrawCallback: function(oSettings) {


      docstable.DataTable().column(0).nodes().each(function (cell, i) {
        var $this = $(this).get(0);
        console.log('this     ',$this.scrollWidth)
});
```

from here i want to be able to measure the td, $this, using $this.offsetWidth & $this.scrollWidth. Unfortunately both are returning 0.

secondly, I don't seem to be able to add classes to the DOM elements even though i can view them in this function. if i console log $this i can see that its a td and i can get the correct value when i run .html().

i need to find out which cells require a tooltip and which don't

Comment: why you want to measure width of each cell? scroll width depends on the tootal width available, and total table width after loading data.

Comment: and to add to DOM elements, you can try $(this).parent() or use closest('div') or whatever element you want

Comment: i'm trying to find out whether the contents of a cell would cause the cell to expand. If the answer is yes, then i wish to add ellipses and a tooltip. The tooltip would not be required on any cells where the contents are within the default width. Thanks for your help!